# How to prevent negative values using logarithmic function

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, taylor-expansion

I have a question on one optimal problem with objective of non-negative constraints.

The results for this problem contains two solution sets: G and F.
While these two solutions should not be negative.

Therefore, the statistical model `PMF (Positive Matrix Factorization)` add two penalty functions to the original optimal function, which can be denoted as:

-$\alpha \sum log(g)$, -$\beta \sum log(f)$.

Then, the problem was solved to minimizing the enhanced optimal objective.

In its offical guideline, it says that

> In practice, the log functions are approximated by a Taylor
> series expansion up to quadratic terms. The algorithm can obtain transient negative values, but it
> immediately adjusts the Taylor expansion so that the user never sees the negative values. Only nonnegative values are stored in factor matrices.

I have little understanding on the process of calculating logarithmic function with Taylor series, and how the algorithm remove the negative solutions. In my opinion, positive g or f close to 0 may lead to very large -$\alpha \sum log(g)$ or -$\beta \sum log(f)$ (then to be removed), while negative g or f could lead to NaN values.

[link-Page 6](https://www3.epa.gov/ttnamti1/files/ambient/pm25/workshop/laymen.pdf)